# R code to divide the age into ranges and get the count of people in that age ranges with regard to another categorical variable

Tags: r

[The image shows part my data set.HD comprises the presence or absence of heart disease.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ZEH.png)

I want to divide the age into ranges as

```
25<Age<=35,35<Age<=45,45<Age<=55,55<Age<=65,65<Age<=75,75<Age<=85
```

and then count the number of people having heart disease in that age ranges. How can I write the R code for this?

Comment: Just check `?cut` and specify the `breaks`

Comment: Take care with formatting; half of your question was missing. And please provide data as text, not images.

Comment: can you provide me with an example. I'm new to R

Comment: will take care of that next time. Thank you neilfws :)

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
```

You can divide into the ranges by cut function and count using the group_by and count function in dplyr:

```
df$group <- cut(df$Age, breaks = seq(25,85,by=10), right = TRUE)
df %>% 
group_by(group) %>%
tally(HD == "present")
```

If you want to see how many people have the disease in each age group and how many do not, replace `tally(HD == "present")` with `count(HD)` in the code above.